# selenium how to deselect the selected element

Tags: automated-testing

[image: Deselect the selected element]

```
<select id="SelectedCustomerRoleIds" multiple="multiple" name="SelectedCustomerRoleIds" data-role="multiselect" aria-disabled="false" style="display: none;" xpath="1">
<option value="1">Administrators</option>
<option value="2">Forum Moderators</option>
<option value="4">Guests</option>
<option value="3" selected="" style="">Registered</option>
<option value="5">Vendors</option></select>
```

I have tried the following code to deselect option 3 - Registered and select option 4 - Guests.

```
WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.id("SelectedCustomerRoleIds")):
Select select = new Select(element): select.deselectByValue("3"): 
select.selectByValue("4")
```

Comment: It would help if we knew why you need to deselect the selected option. There are several ways, but knowing the reason will affect which method is better for you.

Comment: because to select another option i need to deselect the selected one .

Comment: In that case I'd recommend editing the selected option to delete the attribute `selected=""` because you want to select a different option in a multi-select. It's faster than clicking the selected option to deselect it then clicking the option you want to select.

Comment: Thanks for responding. this is the method I have used to deselect and select a different option but still coming with error.                                                                     WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.id("SelectedCustomerRoleIds")):             Select select = new Select(element):                                                                                    select.deselectByValue("3"):                                                                                                 select.selectByValue("4"):

Comment: What is the error you receive, and what is the language you are using?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to select or unselect the selected element. Whereas, in test automation services most comm ways are as follow.

1. Create a locator for the element and click on the same using different ways like action class, Java script or simple click.
2. Usiing deselect by Text

   Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("Locator xpath")));
   dropdown.deselectByText("Registered");
3. Deselecting using value

   Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("Locator xpath")));
   dropdown.deselectByValue("3");